# Modelagem de jogo

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

[image: Enunciado][image: Enunciado]O jogo será de combates entre pares de personagens.

As classes que são pedidas para implementar as seguintes: `Personagem` (classe abstrata) -> `Orc` / `Humanos` (interfaces) -> `Arqueiro` (Humano) / `Ogro` (Orc).

Em resumo, tem uma classe abstrata `Personagens`, abaixo dela duas classes de interface (`Humano` e `Orc`) e abaixo dessas classes como as classes `Arqueiro`, e outras duas que são `Humanos` e `Ogros` e outras duas que são `Orc`.

No enunciado tem os atributos para cada tipo de personagem e os valores para tal.

Os atributos eu devo defini-los na classe abstrata `Personagem` ou na interface referente de cada personagem? Lembrando que cada tipo de personagem tem atributos diferentes.

Não enunciado pede para criar dois vetores de 100 posições, um vetor para cada tipo (`Orc` e `Humano`). Eu posso criar vetores de interface? Se sim, como acessar os objetos?

Comment: Certo, eu entendi o que vc quis dizer. Talvez eu deixei meio confuso mesmo. Vou colocar fotos do enunciado para ficar mais claro. Obrigado!

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

O que você chama de atributo, e deve ter aprendido por algum material que usa o nome errado, na verdade [chama-se campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Campos comuns podem ir na classe abstrata, os específicos em outros derivadas. Se não há nada em comum ou o que tem em comum é circunstancial, não faz sentido ter classe abstrata.

Acho estranho cada tipo de personagem ser uma interface. Mais estranho ainda é dar a entender que as interfaces herdam de classe, o que é impossível. Pode ser que sua pergunta esteja confusa, mas se for o que está no enunciado eu acho que deve fugir disso (de fato depois da edição percebe-se que o enunciado desensina).

Pode criar vetores de qualquer tipo, incluindo de interfaces. Claro que na hora de colocar um elemento ele precisa ser concreto e deve ser um tipo que implemente essa interface. O acesso é feito normalmente, não há diferença.